# My website is not being responsive on some mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, zurb-foundation

I have [my website](http://www.coding-kids.net) and I have been making it responsive with a mixture of bootstrap, foundation and w3.css. To test that it works on small screens, I have been resizing the browser window on my laptop to mimic a mobile device. It has worked fine, and I have now published my site. However, I have come to test it on my iPod touch 5 (which mimics and apple device) and it does not show the responsive version. I tried it on my android phone, too, and it is not responsive. I have tried it on a windows phone, though, and it works fine. I have not been relying on technology that detects which device you are on, only on screen width. I think this problem may be something to do with the screen resolution. Here is the CSS that controls my website:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a
    {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus
    {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus
    {
        background-color: #0089ff;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 767px)
{
    body
    {
        padding-top: 230px;
    }
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu
    {
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    body
    {
        padding-top: 130px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    #resize
    {
        width: 30%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px)
{
    #alignp
    {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

As I said, I have used this along with bootstrap, foundation and w3.css, all standard versions. I hope you can help.

Comment: pay attention to body styles because you overwrite them max-width:767 and min-width:767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have this in head `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.
Chrome also has a device mode where you can simulate different devices

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. What was the problem before? What does that extra tag do?

Comment: makes the media to report to the device width not to a normal  "deskop" width

Answer (score 1):

you can always test it with different device in your browser. check out ripple extenstion for google chrome. it's realy useful extention.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc

Comment: it works fine like that, so maybe it is the screen resolution